# Sonarqube with Jenkins and sonarqube runner

Tags: jenkins

We have configured SOnarqube with Jenkins and sonarqube runner.
Getting following error on building:
Can you please help:

NFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
>       at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>       at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
>       at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
>       at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
>       at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
>       at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The svn blame command [svn blame --xml --non-interactive -x -w ext/projectmgt/ProjectNumberAutoSuggestion.java] failed: svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command
>   svn: E155036: The working copy at 'C:\CodeReview\JenkinsHome\jobs\Test\workspace'
>   is too old (format 29) to work with client version '1.8.13 (r1667537)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.

```
at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:110)
at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.access$000(SvnBlameCommand.java:45)
at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand$1.call(SvnBlameCommand.java:91)
at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand$1.call(SvnBlameCommand.java:88)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks pretty clear to me. The workspace was checked out with an older version of SVN, below 1.8. When sonar is trying to run, it is using SVN 1.8 which won't work if the workspace was checked out with a previous SVN version. There are two options here:

1. Delete the workspace and do the checkout with SVN 1.8
2. Configure Jenkins to use the same version of SVN you used to check out the code.